# Can we get a facebook access token by providing email and password in the code?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, access-token, facebook-authentication

I would like to get the photo urls from the from this album:

https://graph.facebook.com/175758929145317/photos

If you access it without providing an access token, then you will get empty data:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

But if you first generate an access token here:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=175758929145317%2Fphotos

And then you append it to the url like this, you can get the data:

https://graph.facebook.com/175758929145317/photos?access_token=your_access_token

However, this access token cannot be used forever, it will expire.

I would like to dynamically take the photo urls from https://graph.facebook.com/175758929145317/photos and display the images on a webpage, the person who views this webpage does not need to have a facebook account.

So every time the webpage is viewed, I am thinking about if it's possible to simply use my facebook account to login (by hardcoding the email and password) and then obtain a new access token so that I can get the photo urls.

Is this possible? Or is there a better solution to my problem? (I cannot ask the album owner to change his album to public)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not possible, you cannot authenticate in FB using hardcoded (or stored) login/password - as per [Facebook policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> **I. Features and Functionality**
>
> ...
>
> 3 - You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or
>   collects Facebook usernames or passwords.

what you can do instead:

1. Get (and then extend) token for yourself (see scenario 4 in this document: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/). That extended token should be good for 60 days - and then you [might be able to extend it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654960/whats-the-purpose-of-renewable-access-tokens/10658009#10658009).
2. Try to get those photos using APPLICATION token - and if it works, then the token is good forever:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Comment: Just tried, method 2 does not work. Method 1 works but I will have to manually update the code with a new token for every 60 days.